# Is it necessary to have multiple html files in require.js?

Tags: backbone.js, webview, requirejs

I made a simple app using backbone.js and require.js. Earlier i used to have just one index.html file and used to dynamically render/hide different views. Now with require.js, i still have index.html file but i have created separate html files for each of my four views in the app, and i put them all in templates folder. Main point is, these four html files don't have the `<!DOCTYPE html></html>` tags, just the `<div>` tags for the view.

I'm not sure this is the right way to do it using require.js. Should i integrate all html code into just one index.html and using `<script>` tags for templating?

Comment: This is the right way. Requirejs is used to manage and load assets dynamically when required and also provides scope. Keeping your way will produce unnecessary global variables

Comment: sorry, didn't get u.. u r saying that it shud b kept in separate html files? if yes, then can u pls say a bit more about why is it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put your templates into one big html file, **`require.js` and `Backbone.js` are the perfect combination** to have everything in highly flexible modules, loaded only when neccessary.

With only a few modules you may not notice their advantages, but trust me, if you write more complex, dynamically growing high speed web applications, you save yourself hours of debugging and refactoring, and your code will be very simple to read and modify.

You have several ways to handle **templates** with Backbone, e.x. `this.$el.html( _.template(template, this.model.toJSON() ))` if you loaded your template into a `template` variable.

**It won't affect speed**, templates are only a few kilobytes. Comparing to the fact that your page is likely to already load a dozen files(many icons, a few images, css-es, js-es) even without `BB.js` or `Require.js` and modules, a new few-kilobyte-big file will not be noticable. Also, you can cache templates after first load if you use `Require.js` to load them.

Answer (score 1):

Depends...

Mostly I would separate them because it fells more organized and easier to maintain, but... if you have too many of them (lets call them "Tiles") it can make your site slow because you will be doing several server trips to draw the site, I've read somewhere that when the browser have to make more than 4 request HTTP at the same time you will be punished for it with a slower performance, I will try to find the source and post here.

If your tiles are always together, I think putting everything in a single HTML with  is ok, so you can fetch all of them with a single HTTP request, but the down side is that when you update a single template the client side cache of all templates goes to hell.

Another solution is to have them in separate files so they are more organized and using a build tool you create a big minified template file that you use on production, but that will require some work.

So you got to find the best way for your site.

P.S:Are you using a templating mechanism ? I find them really helpful in this situations.

Comment: I like your answer, however, my html files are not on server. It's in my app itself. and although there are multiple html files, only one, index.html file is having <!DOCTYPE html></html> tags, rest of the html files are simply html structure using <div></div> tags. I use them for templating.

Comment: I use Underscore.js for templates